# How to add nodes with the same name in a loop?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create the following XML file:

```
<Clientes>
  <Cliente>
    <Name>sfsdfsd</Name>
    <Phone>
    </Phone>
    <Matriculas>
      <Matricula>
        <Nr>567856786</Nr>
        <Marca>86786</Marca>
        <Modelo>8678678</Modelo>
      </Matricula>
      <Matricula>
        <Nr>u56u5u</Nr>
        <Marca>4564b5</Marca>
        <Modelo>b456b</Modelo>
      </Matricula>
    </Matriculas>
  </Cliente>
</Clientes>
```

I have several clientes stored in a List and each of them may have more then one Matricula, stored in a List

i have the following code:

```
foreach (Cliente c in cli)
{
    XmlNode xCliente = xDoc.CreateElement("Cliente");
    XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
    XmlNode xPhone = xDoc.CreateElement("Phone");
    XmlNode xMatriculas = xDoc.CreateElement("Matriculas");
    XmlNode xMatricula = xDoc.CreateElement("Matricula");
    XmlNode xNr = xDoc.CreateElement("Nr");
    XmlNode xMarca = xDoc.CreateElement("Marca");
    XmlNode xModelo = xDoc.CreateElement("Modelo");
    xName.InnerText = c.Name;
    xPhone.InnerText = c.Phone;
    xCliente.AppendChild(xName);
    xCliente.AppendChild(xPhone);
    foreach (Matricula m in c.matricula)
    {
        xNr.InnerText = m.nr;
        xMarca.InnerText = m.marca;
        xModelo.InnerText = m.modelo;
        xMatricula.AppendChild(xNr);
        xMatricula.AppendChild(xMarca);
        xMatricula.AppendChild(xModelo);
        xMatriculas.AppendChild(xMatricula);
    }
    xCliente.AppendChild(xMatriculas);
    xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xCliente);
}
```

i can add several Cliente to the root, but only the last Matricula in Matriculas is added.

Comment: You may want to learn a bit about object references before you try and write serious code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move

```
 XmlNode xMatricula = xDoc.CreateElement("Matricula");
 XmlNode xNr = xDoc.CreateElement("Nr");
 XmlNode xMarca = xDoc.CreateElement("Marca");
 XmlNode xModelo = xDoc.CreateElement("Modelo");
```

inside the inner for loop.

You are reusing the exact same node, you need to create a new node every time you want a new node in your document.

Comment: tkx for the quick answer, that did the job :)